# Clickable tr but not the child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently, I have a table and each row has bound a function at the click event.

HTML:

```
<tr class="clickable">
...... 
  <td class="text-center">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right text-left">
            <li><a href="#mymodalpath"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> View details</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#mymodalpath" data-toggle="ajaxModal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', ".clickable", function (e) { /*something*/ });
```

I read about e.stopPropagation() method but I need something dynamic because, for example, in the above example, the dropdown-menu is an external plugin that I can't manage.

--- EDIT
Is there a way to handle the click of the TR but not trigger on the child elements?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You seem to have misplaced your question.

Comment: I tried to bind this: $(document).on('click', ".clickable:not(.dropdown-menu)", function (e) { /*something*/ });
 but it doesn't work

Comment: @Malk I'm sorry, Is there a way to handle the click of the TR but not trigger on the child elements?

Comment: still not clear what objective is. Please explain desired behavior properly

Comment: If I click on the tr and on the dropdown, now, is fired the same handler ( $(document).on('click', ".clickable", function (e) { /*something*/ }); ). Whereas I want to fire the previous handler just if I click on the tr and not into the dropdown.

Comment: @MatteoMartinelli `if(event.target === this)`???

Answer (score 3):

Due to event propagation, clicking on a child element will automatically propagate up until it reaches the parent `.clickable` who has the event.  The only way `e.stopPropagation()` will work is if you put event handlers on all the children so it stopped moving up to the parent, probably not something you want to do.  Instead, you can just check the event and see exactly what is actually triggering the call...

```
$(document).on('click', ".clickable", function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('clickable')) {
    // target is the exact element that is being clicked on, you can test if it is the one
    // one with the 'clickable' class name, or however you want to distinguish it.  If it
    // doesn't get in here, then it is some child element you don't care about.
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a space and > in your selector. Without the space you're selecting .clickable but not .dropdown-menu, with the space it's selecting .clickable excluding descendant .dropdown-menu

```
$(document).on('click', ".clickable > :not(.dropdown-menu)", function (e) { 
    /*something*/ 
});
```

Comment: @MatteoMartinelli Not sure what happened to my comment here but the updated version with ">" is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking returning if you hit the class you are looking for

```
$(document).on('click', ".clickable", function (e) { 
  if ($(this).hasClass("dropdown-toggle")) {
    return;
  }
  /*something*/ 

});
```

Comment: Ok, thank, could work but, if I have 1000 different element (and not just the dropdown), how can i do?

Comment: You can do the inverse `if(!$(this).hasClass("clickable"))`

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that you want to fire a specific function based on the  that was clicked?

The best way to do this is to switch based on the e.target - the element that was the target of the click. Like so:

```js
$(document).on('click', ".clickable", function (e) { 
  if (e.target.id == 'foo') { // assuming your .clickable element has an id
    foo(); // call some function. 
  }
});
```

I think this pattern will get you close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('ul.dropdown-menu, ul.dropdown-menu *') ) {
        return false;
    }
    alert( e.target.nodeName );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="clickable">
  <td class="text-center">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right text-left">
            <li><a href="#mymodalpath"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> View details</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#mymodalpath" data-toggle="ajaxModal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the `target` is part of dropdown. WIll use `closest()` as a way to see if target is any part of the dropdown tree.

```
$(document).on('click', ".clickable", function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length) {
     /* don't do anything since target is within dropdown */
     return;
  }

   /* do something here we've already assured it isn't dropdown */

});
```

Reference [**closest() docs**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

You could check the tagName of the target that caused the event to fire.

Note that the [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property is provided to us by jQuery, so it may not exist.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yfm4wrf2/1/)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function(e)
{
    if(e.target != undefined && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "SELECT")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("do stuff");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class='clickable'>
        <td style='width:500px;border: 5px solid red;'>
            <select>
              <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
              <option value="saab">Saab</option>
              <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
              <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```